How to maintain consistent element positioning in Elementor Pro editor with the sidebar panel open?
I am new to WordPress and currently developing a webpage using Elementor Pro. While working in the editor, I’ve noticed that the left-hand sidebar panel (which contains the toolbar and widgets) affects the page's width during editing.
When the sidebar is open, the width of the page in the editor differs from the final layout, and the elements I place are positioned differently than they appear in the published version. Closing the sidebar shows the full-width page, but it doesn’t allow me to make real-time modifications to the elements.
How do developers typically address this issue? Is there a way to reposition the sidebar panel or any other method to ensure I can work with a full-width view while still being able to edit the elements?
